# How to Populate combobox form oracle database?

Tags: c#, oracle, combobox, oracle11g

I am trying to populate a `combobox` form oracle database then according to
the selected value from `combobox` I want to automatically fill `textbox1`, `textbox2` and `textbox3`

here is the code i am trying to use to fill the `combobox` but 
first problem is that `combobox` loads empty 
second i want to learn how to fill the other `textboxs` automatically

please if anyone can help me or explain to me

```
    public void Fillcombobox()
    {
        string connstr = "data source=db;user id=user;password=pwd;";
        string cmdtxt = "select product_id, description from products";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt,conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            CB_PRODUCT_ID.DisplayMember = "product_id";
            CB_PRODUCT_ID.ValueMember = "description";

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // what should I d to fill other textboxs ?
                TB_PRODUCTS.Text = ???;
            }
        }

    }

    private void CB_PRODUCT_ID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fillcombobox();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to *combine* all the values from the cursor by, say, `List<String>`:

```
    public void Fillcombobox()
    {
        //TODO: do not hardcode connection string (esp. password), but load it
        string connstr = "data source=db;user id=user;password=pwd;";

        string cmdtxt = 
          @"select product_id, 
                   description 
              from products";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // reader is IDisposable and should be closed
            using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                List<String> items = new List<String>();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(String.Format("{0}, {1}", dr.GetValue(0), dr.GetValue(1)));
                } 

                TB_PRODUCTS.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
            }

        }

    }
```

**Edit**: To update TextBoxes (`textbox1`, textbox2 and textbox3) I suggest using `Combobox` event `TextChanged`:

```
private void TB_PRODUCTS_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;

  // Either explicitly or via cb.SelectedIndex
  textbox1.Text = cb.Text;
}
```

Comment: I have tied that but all values of the `combobox` are in one line i tried to replace the sb.Append(Convert.ToString(dr["YourCoumnName"])); with sb.Appendline(Convert.ToString(dr["YourCoumnName"])); but thats wont help

Comment: @samer: I'm sorry, but it seems that you have to combine items with `List<String>`, not with `StringBuilder`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: i got two errors 1- The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: 2- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'object[]'

Comment: at that line TB_PRODUCTS.Items.AddRange(items); as u know TB_PRODUCTS is a combobox am i right ?

Comment: Let's put it as `TB_PRODUCTS.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());`

Comment: Great thats works fine.. but bow about changing the values of `textbox1` ,`textbox2`, ,`textbox3` according to the value of `combobox`?

Comment: @samer: I suggest using `TextChanged` event of the `TB_PRODUCTS `combobox

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (dr.Read())
            {
                TB_PRODUCTS.Text = dr["YourColumnName"].toString();
            }
```

Comment: You should *combine* values from the reader, but not *rewrite*

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @ ryanyuyu you are right, the main question was how to change the values of textbox1 ,textbox2, ,textbox3 according to the value of combobox?